# An explicit negative solution to the Lüroth problem for non-algebraically closed fields

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, birational-geometry, invariant-theory, geometric-invariant-theory

Let $\mathsf{k}$ be a field of characteristic $0$, and consider $\mathsf{k}(x,y)$.

If $\mathsf{k}$ is algebraically closed, then every field $L$ such that the inclusion $\mathsf{k} \subset L \subset \mathsf{K}(x,y)$ holds is a purely transcendental extension of the base field (i.e., Castelnuovo's Theorem implies a positive solution to the Lüroth problem in two dimensions).

Now suppose that $\mathsf{k}$ is **not algebraically closed**.

Question: can we have a finite group $G$ of field automorphisms of $\mathsf{k}(x,y)$, fixing $\mathsf{k}$, such that $\mathsf{k}(x,y)^G$ is not a purely transcendental extension of $\mathsf{k}$?

I am looking for an explicit example of $G$ such that $\mathsf{k}(x,y)^G$ is not rational.

Comment: @PaceNielsen yes I wanted the field fixed. I wil edit the question. Nice argument though!

Comment: In positive characteristic if you allow finite group schemes, there are such examples with field of invariants general type.

Comment: @Mohan this is very interesting. Do you have an easy example/reference for such an example?

Comment: I think they are called Zariski surfaces. May be you could look them up.

Comment: This version of the Luroth problem for the fields of invariants is sometimes called the Noether problem: https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Noether_problem#:~:text=The%20question%20of%20the%20rationality,a%20field%20of%20rational%20functions.&text=In%20general%2C%20the%20answer%20to%20Noether's%20problem%20is%20negative.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the first paragraph in Shafarevich's paper "On Luroth's problem" (found here [http://www.math.ens.fr/~benoist/refs/Shafarevich.pdf](http://www.math.ens.fr/%7Ebenoist/refs/Shafarevich.pdf)) the field of rational functions on the surface $z^2+y^2=x^3-x$ over $\mathbb{R}$ is an example of a non-rational field $F$, containing $\mathbb{R}$ of transcendence degree $2$, that embeds in $\mathbb{R}(u,v)$ (fixing $\mathbb{R}$).  I don't know whether or not this embedding can be chosen so that $\mathbb{R}(u,v)/F$ is Galois.

Comment: This gives an example of a non-rational subfield of $k(x,y)$, but does it arise as the fixed field under some group $G$ of automorphisms of $k(x,y)$? (I don't think that is automatic, is it?)

Comment: I second that. It does not seem clear to me how this field is of the form $\mathbb{R}(x,y)^G$ for an appropriate finite $G$. But I might be missing something.

Comment: Just to amplify: of course it is not automatic for a subfield $L$ of $k(x,y)$ (with the degree of the extension assumed finite) to be the field of invariants under some group $G$. If it were, then it would have to be Galois, but e.g. $k(x^3,y) \subset k(x,y)$ is not a Galois extension if $k$ does not contain a primitive 3rd root of unity.

Comment: So the next step would probably be to work out the embedding that Shafarevich claims exists, find its degree, and check if it is Galois.

Comment: @PaceNielsen thank you very much for suggestion. I will check if the embedding can be made as a Galois extension. Luckly, yes.

Comment: Geometrically, the question translates into degree of unirationality of this surface. Namely, if there is a degree two dominant rational map from $\mathbf{P}^2$ to this cubic, then the corresponding field extension would automatically be Galois. Typically, degree two parametrization of cubic hypersurfaces comes from a line defined over a ground field, as in http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/~huybrech/Notes.pdf, Corollary 1.18. However in this case the only line I see (at infinity) is passing through singular points, and the construction doesn't work.

Comment: Higher degree unirational parametrizations of cubics with a rational point are explained in https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0005146.pdf.